# how to calculate earliest leap year in formula field salesforce

Tags: formula-field

I am writing a formula where I need a logic for calculating the earliest **leap year**.

> **Formula**

```
(Sum(Mort1, Mort2, Mort3)*1.08^(current year-earliest LP year))+water+ECB+Taxes
```

What logic we can apply for earliest LP year?

Comment: What does your above formula corresponds to?

Comment: its a currency formula.

Answer (score 2):

Your question made me think and this is what I have come up with. In [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214019/method-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year) article, from **Microsoft** gave me all the necessary details to calculate **Leap Year**, it says

> To determine whether a year is a leap year, follow these steps:
>
> 1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to
>    step 5.
> 2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3.
>    Otherwise, go to step 4.
> 3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go
>    to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 4. The year is a leap year (it has
>    366 days).
> 5. The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

To make matters simpler they have included an Excel formula as well

```
=IF(OR(MOD(YearValCell,400)=0,AND(MOD(YearValCell,4)=0,MOD(YearValCell,100)<>0)),"Leap Year", "NOT a Leap Year")
```

Now, I had to make few tweaks and additional logic implementation to make it work on Salesforce and then complete your requirements. Enough said, **final** version of the `formula` is

```
IF(OR(
   MOD( Year( Today() ),400)=0,
   AND(
       MOD(Year( Today() ),4)=0,
       MOD(Year( Today() ),100)<>0
       )
     )
,Text(Year(Today())) & " is Leap Year", 
   IF(OR(
       MOD( Year( Today() )-1,400)=0,
       AND(
           MOD(Year( Today() )-1,4)=0,
           MOD(Year( Today() )-1,100)<>0
           )
         )
   ,Text(Year(Today())-1) & " is Leap Year", "Logic for Year (Today)-2"
   )
)
```

> **Result**

What was all that if it doesn't show what you want, right? :)
I added that field on **Task** object just for reference, you can create the field on your desired object, and the screenshot is given below

[image]

P.S. Before you may ask, Formula field I created for this drill is of type **text**, hence the casting of `Text(Year(today() ))`.

Comment: thank you Mahmood..... your logic is correct. But i implemented as per my need(logic in below answer).

Comment: Your formula calculation is fine but it is not foolproof, I afraid. For example, year 2100, which is very far from now, I know, is gonna be a **leap year** as per your calculation but in reality it is not. It is just an example. Secondly, you could create a separate field for year calculation and refer it in your Currency calculation formula field, for **simplicity**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have used below formula and it is working as per my requirement:

```
(( Mort__c + Mort2__c + Mort3__c) 
* (1.08 ^(YEAR( TODAY())+1- 
if(MOD( YEAR( TODAY() )-1, 4 ) = 0,YEAR(TODAY())-1, 
if(MOD(YEAR( TODAY() )-2,4)=0,YEAR(TODAY())-2, 
if(MOD(YEAR( TODAY() )-3,4)=0,YEAR(TODAY())-3, 
if(MOD(YEAR( TODAY() )-4,4)=0,YEAR(TODAY())-4, 
YEAR( TODAY()))))))))
+ water__c 
+ ECB__c 
+ Taxes__c
```